# Any easier way for finding selectors, while building Appium test framework for Cordova iOS app

Tags: ios, css, cordova, xpath, appium-ios

I am working on automating a iOS app using Appium-Java.

While writing the Page objects we need to find identifiers (`driver.findelement`) or when UI changes.

Currently its tedious job, as manually need to traverse through till required screen & then write the selectors( n CSS / XPath / XCUnit based Xpath)

1. Currently, there's no easy way to test CSS selectors / XPath (unlike web where we can test it then & there on Firefox / chrome using browser add-ons)
2. Is there any way to invoke certain screen directly instead of traversing from the starting point in iOS/Android native app or Cordova based app, while writing the selectors?

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a Cordova-based iOS app, you can use [wd](https://github.com/admc/wd) and [wd-bridge](https://github.com/sebv/wd-bridge) to provide a mechanism to allow Appium to communicate directly with the Webview, enabling you to use CSS selectors.

[This blog post](http://rolandoldengarm.com/index.php/2016/02/18/how-to-automatically-test-your-non-angular-cordova-or-ionic-app/) gives a great tutorial on how to setup such a test environment using Protractor/Jasmine.

You can then write Protractor tests which allow you to reference your app UI elements as HTML components, e.g.:

```
describe('Testing the app', function () {
  it('01. should have a header', function () {
    var header = element(by.id('header'));
    expect(header.getAttribute('class')).toContain('toolbar');
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But in general how to speed-up process of identifying locators for Native apps automation. In case of web we have firebug, firepath etc. and you can directly jump to intended screen in most of the cases to test the locator you constructed. How to achieve the same in case of Native App?

Comment: Your question is entitled `for Cordova iOS app` and so this answer relates to a Cordova iOS app, not a native iOS app. But anyway, while it's possible to jump between screens of a Cordova iOS app using the Webview context simply by changing window.location or invoking an app-side JS function, I'm not aware of any way of achieving the same in a native app.

Comment: Thanks. Do we have an example on using wd / wd-bridge using Java?

Comment: wd is a Javascript module not Java

Comment: Hi, Do you have latest link for WD/ Appium using Node.js example? Many thanks